# Why would a route method not work in my layout?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, view

Rake Routes lists:

```
program_reports GET    /programs/:program_id/reports(.:format)               reports#index
```

Yet putting this in a layout file (programs.html.erb)

```
<li><%= link_to "Reports", program_reports(@program_id) %></li>
```

gives me an error:

```
undefined method `program_reports' for #<#<Class:0x007fe98d44baf0>:0x007fe98d465ce8>
```

I don't know if this matters, but note that the layout is part of a nested layout structure, and so the view is rendered with something like this:

```
respond_with @partocipants do |format|
  format.html {
    render layout: 'layouts/progtabs'
  }
end
```

Any idea what is wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'program_reports' route provides 'program_reports_path' and 'program_reports_url' to your views. Try:

```
<li><%= link_to "Reports", program_reports_path(@program_id) %></li>
```